# How do I open GRASS layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, layers

I'm quite a newbie to QGIS and GRASS.. I have installed QGIS 2.10.1 with GRASS 6.4.3 on my Windows 7 laptop and wish to open GRASS layers in QGIS. If I got it right, you can use the QGIS built-in browser for this. So, for example, I wish to see the "elements" vector layer:
[image: Example browser and layer windows]

I try to drag the folder (created with GRASS topology tools) to the Layers window. But nothing happens, the folder doesn't move with the mouse. Should it move, or is this perhaps some Windows issue? Or am I missing some very elementary skill with QGIS?

Comment: It doesn't look like QGIS is recognizing that folder as a GRASS location. Was the GRASS integration stuff installed properly with QGIS?

Comment: Well I installed a QGIS package that already contained GRASS as  a plugin. I made some topological analyses in the GUI, and they had a View Output button that worked well, it showed the  layers in QGIS. But when I reopen QGIS, I'm not able to drag the GRASS layers to QGIS anymore.

Comment: Not quite sure what fixed the problem, but it may have been an integration related issue as you mentioned. I used the New Mapset wizard from QGIS->Plugins->GRASS to create a new location and mapset, and now the dragging works. If I recall, I initially created a mapset using only the standalone version of GRASS. So it may be that you have to do it from within QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see at below image, I have 2 'location' (tiznados and utah) in my GRASS Database whose name is 'datagrass'.

[image]

If I want to load a map at the Map Canvas, I have to drag a file, for example **utah_demUTM2** (red rectangle); not a folder. The result is:

[image]

However, I can't use the map yet. I need to select GRASS mapset (see next image).

[image]

At this point, I can use GRASS modules because they were activated (see GRASS Tools window).

Comment: Hi,  thanks everybody for clarification, I've got it working!