# Grass toolbar for QGIS 2.14.18

Tags: qgis-plugins, toolbar, qgis-grass-plugin

The GRASS plugin toolbar appears incomplete in QGIS 2.14.18.
I can open the mapset but I'm not finding how to load (open) an existing layer.
[image: qgis grass plugin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only learning myself, however, this may help. Try opening a 'browser' window (view>panels>browser) and navigating to your GRASS database folder. You should see your location folder there in the directory tree - as I recall, right-clicking on the vector or raster set in the mapset will give you the option to add the map - double clicking works as well. You may also see a GRASS icon in the directory tree - if so, use that option as first preference.

Comment: Ok.  We can see a related answer at [How do I open GRASS layers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163316/how-do-i-open-grass-layers-in-qgis)